# How to show the correct video-image from calibrated camera stream?

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, fisheye

I recently studied OpenCV. My task: to display a calibrated image from an action camera. I calibrated the camera. I can easily get a good calibrated image.

```py
#CODE TO WORK WITH IMAGE
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys

#Matrix
DIM = (1280,720)
K = np.array([[670.6687634787847, 0.0, 625.8352066309077], [0.0, 665.8169620465114, 349.9286858249417], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])
D = np.array([[-0.01833489984490284], [0.12136347203846999], [-0.4637418712120781], [0.5817376362743433]])

img = cv2.imread("C:\Test\Fish_eye_remove\Test.jpg")
h, w = img.shape[:2]
map1, map2 = cv2.fisheye.initUndistortRectifyMap(K, D, np.eye(3), K, DIM, cv2.CV_16SC2)
undistorted_img = cv2.remap(img, map1, map2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
cv2.imshow("undistorted", undistorted_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

but when I try to work with frames in the video, I get a cropped image on the output. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

```py
#CODE TO WORK WITH VIDEO-IMAGE
import numpy as np
import cv2

DIM = (1280,720)
K = np.array([[670.6687634787847, 0.0, 625.8352066309077], [0.0, 665.8169620465114, 349.9286858249417], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])
D = np.array([[-0.01833489984490284], [0.12136347203846999], [-0.4637418712120781], [0.5817376362743433]])

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    flag, img = cap.read()
    try:
        map1, map2 = cv2.fisheye.initUndistortRectifyMap(K, D, np.eye(3), K, DIM, cv2.CV_16SC2)
        calibrated = cv2.remap(img, map1, map2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
        cv2.imshow('result', calibrated)
    except:
        cap.release()
        raise

    k = cv2.waitKey(30)
    if k == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I get a cropped and distorted image

[image]

Comment: "I can easily get a good calibrated image, but when I try to work with frames in the video...".
Add code that worked for you please.

Comment: @Oliort I added it in my question. You can see it now

Comment: was the test undistorted image taken with same camera? what the dimensions of it

Comment: @chris yeah, test image was taken from same camera. Resolution is 1280x720

Comment: if you use the VideoCapture once in the working code instead of loading an offline image, does it still work? Maybe the cam is capturing in wrong image size? Btw. in the live mode you should initialize the maps only once!

Comment: can you test and print the dimensions of img?

Comment: @Micka I tested my code with offline video-image, and it works correctly. I'm completely confused

Comment: @Micka I just added CAP_PROP_FRAME for camera dimensions and it worked! thx 4 help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx all for help!
I solved my problem this way:
I realized that the camera image was in the wrong resolution. I just added `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280) cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)` and it worked!